# Dependency errors when trying to install i386 packages

Tags: apt, 20.04, printing, 32-bit, canon

I'm trying to install the Printer Canon LBP2900 in Ubuntu 20.04.

Canon has Linux drivers for the printer on [their homepage](https://www.canon.de/support/consumer_products/products/printers/laser/i-sensys_lbp2900.html?type=drivers&language=&os=linux) and I successfully installed them.
But they are not working out of the box. I found many sources, saying that the drivers are dependent on some 32bit packages that have to be installed manually to make it work (the solution seems to work well for older Ubuntu versions, 16.04 and 18.04). But in 20.04 it is not working:

Trying to install the packages in 20.04:

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install libatk1.0-0:i386 libcairo2:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libpango1.0-0:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libpopt0:i386 libxml2:i386 libc6:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libpango-1.0-0:i386' instead of 'libpango1.0-0:i386'
libc6:i386 is already the newest version (2.31-0ubuntu9).
libpopt0:i386 is already the newest version (1.16-14).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libatk1.0-0:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.55.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libcairo2:i386 : Depends: libfontconfig1:i386 (>= 2.12.6) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libfreetype6:i386 (>= 2.9.1) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libpng16-16:i386 (>= 1.6.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libgtk2.0-0:i386 : Depends: libcups2:i386 (>= 2.3~b6) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libfontconfig1:i386 (>= 2.12.6) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.22.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.41.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.28.3) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.28.3) but it is not going to be installed
                    Recommends: libgail-common:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libpango-1.0-0:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.59.2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libharfbuzz0b:i386 (>= 2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libxml2:i386 : Depends: liblzma5:i386 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

It comes down to the issue, that Ubuntu denies installation for good reasons:

```
$ sudo apt install zlib1g:i386

... LONG LIST OF PACKAGES INSTALLED AND REMOVED ...

WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  apt adduser (due to apt) gpgv (due to apt) libapt-pkg6.0 (due to apt) dash
  dpkg (due to dash) debconf (due to dash) zlib1g (due to dpkg) grep
  install-info (due to grep) gzip init systemd-sysv (due to init)
  init-system-helpers (due to init) perl-base (due to init-system-helpers)
  login libpam0g (due to login) libpam-runtime (due to login)
  libpam-modules (due to login) mount util-linux (due to mount) sysvinit-utils
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1109 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Of course I won't because I know exactly what it would do ;-)

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy zlib1g zlib1g:i386
zlib1g:
  Installiert:           1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.1
  Installationskandidat: 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.1
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
zlib1g:i386:
  Installiert:           (keine)
  Installationskandidat: 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1
  Versionstabelle:
     1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
```

---

- **How can I still install these dependencies?**
- **Are there any replacements?**

Comment: for a wild shot `apt-cache policy zlib1g zlib1g:i386`  On my system I have zlib1g:i386. which packages would be removed?

Comment: @user535733 sure, they are available, but I cannot install them, please see my update.

Comment: both versions lies on my system in focal-updates. maybe mirror error, or you have not focal-updates enabled. Check this.

Comment: Indeed, I had focal-updates disabled... that is the solution, it works now. Please write an answer. Thanks so much!